# MySql type char select max number

Tags: mysql, char, max, min

how select max or min number from colums of type char?

Function max return max lenght.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add zero in your column

```
select max(column + 0), min(column + 0)
```

By adding zero to a column mysql cast column to integer